# How does scoping in loops work? Or: How print(paste(...)) can change the result of code

Tags: r

In the following snipped I am assigning functions to spots in a list.
The result changes depending on whether I am using a `paste` in the loop. I would, up to now, have guessed that calling print would not change any objects, so I am very confused.
In particular, I would be interested how I should create functions in a loop, such that they stay different.

```
g <- function(x){
    function(y){
        10*x + y
    }
}

#############  

test <- list()

x=1

test[[x]] <- g(x)
test[[x]](1) # 11

x=2
test[[x]] <- g(x)
test[[x]](1) # 21
test[[1]](1) # still 11
####

test2 <- list()

for(z in 1:2){
    test2[[z]] <- g(z)
}

test2[[1]](1) # 21 Without print

###

test3 <- list()

for(z in 1:2){
    test3[[z]] <- g(z)
    print(paste("z=",z,"Result=",test3[[z]](1)))
}

test3[[1]](1) # 11 with print
```

Comment: It's not a scoping issue.  It's lazy evaluation.  By default, R expressions are only evaluated when they're "needed".  Printing an object inside the loop means its value is needed inside the loop.  Without the `print`, it's not needed until outside the loop, when the loop index has a single, out-of-bounds value.  This is a very common cause of errors and is why I prefer `lapply` to `for`, since `lapply` forces evaluation.

Comment: See, for example, [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments).